# Regex to get delimited content with egrep

Tags: regex, bash, cygwin, grep

I would like to get the parameter (without parantheses) of a function call with a regular expression.

I am using `egrep` in a bash script with cygwin.

This is what I got so far (with parantheses):

```sh
$ echo "require(catch.me)" | egrep -o '\((.*?)\)'
(catch.me)
```

What would be the right regex here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2002/06/regexp.html

What are you looking for - is a lookbehind and lookahead regular expressions.

`Egrep` cannot do that. `grep` with perl support can do that.

from `man grep`:

```
 -P, --perl-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.  This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
```

So

```
$> echo "require(catch.me)" | grep -o -P '(?<=\().*?(?=\))'
catch.me
```

Comment: Thanks! But wouldn't this be enough? (removed the ? after .*) `echo "require(catch.me)" | grep -o -P '(?<=\().*(?=\))'`

Comment: In that case - yes. But it depends on context of your problem. `?` - is for non-greedy regular expression.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use sed then the following would work -

```
echo "require(catch.me)" | sed 's/.*[^(](\(.*\))/\1/'
```

You can modify your existing regex to this

```
echo "require(catch.me)" | egrep -o 'c.*e'
```

Even though egrep offers this (from the man page)

```
-o, --only-matching
              Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.
```

It isn't really the correct utility. SED and AWK are masters at this. You will have much more control using either SED or AWK. :)

Comment: Just to tag onto this; greps don't print the capture group, they print the entire match. I don't know of way to tell grep to do that. I'd usually bust out another tool.

Comment: @AIG : `grep -o` does specifically only print the capture group! It is a very well-hidden feature.

Answer (score -1):

From the manual :

```
   grep, egrep, fgrep - print lines matching a pattern
```

Basically, grep is used to print the complete line, so you won't do anything more.

What you should do is using another tool, maybe perl, for such operations.

Comment: OP is using the -o flag, which prints only the matching portion of the line.